# Syncing Marketing Cloud opt-in's back to CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud setup using the Connector package (which is up to date). When unsubscribing via the Subscription Centre in MC this rolls back into Sales Cloud, but when the Subscriber resubscribes this change is not reflected in the Sales Cloud.

Any ideas what the issue is here? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: This *should* work, what have Support said?

Comment: They are currently investigating

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Support have confirm the only circumstances that the status is sent back to CRM is the following:

- If the Subscriber has opted out via RMM
- If the Subscriber has opted out via the one-click unsubscribe or subscription centre links.